# How to print out a numbered list in Python 3

Tags: python, list, numbers, integer, python-3.4

How do I print out the index location of each of a python list so that it starts at 1, rather than 0. Here's an idea of what I want it to look like:

```
    blob = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
    for i in blob:
        print(???)
```

Output:

```
1   a
2   b
3   c
4   d
5   e
```

What I need to know is how do I get those numbers to show up alongside what I'm trying to print out? I can get a-e printed out no problem, but I can't figure out how to number the list.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You would need to enumerate your list. That means that for every letter, it has a corrosponding number.

Here is an example of your working code:

```
blob = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]

for number, letter in enumerate(blob):
    print(number, letter)
```

The `enumerate` function will give the variable `number` the position of the variable `letter` in your list every loop.

To display them, you can just use `print(number, letter)` to display them side by side.

Comment: No problem, if this helped you, please accept it to make it the official answer.

Answer (score 7):

```
for a, b in enumerate(blob, 1):
    print '{} {}'.format(a, b)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using built-in operations:

Edit: In case you need extra space:

```
s1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
for i in s1:
    print(s1.index(i) +1, end=' ')
    print(" ",i)
```

Output:

```
1   a
2   b
3   c
4   d
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this one-liner.

```
print(list(enumerate(blob)))
```

to start with index 1

```
print(list(enumerate(blob, start=1)))
```

Codes above will print everthing in one line. If you want to print each element in a new line

```
from pprint import pprint  # no install required
pprint(list(enumerate(blob, start=1)), depth=2)
```

Answer (score 1):

One-liner pretty printing of `enumerate` object:

```
myList = ['a', 'b', 'c']
print(*enumerate(myList), sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
(0, 'a')
(1, 'b')
(2, 'c')
```

If one want to control the output format use this (with your own formatting):

```
print('\n'.join(['{}-{}'.format(i, val) for i, val in (enumerate(myList))]))
```

Output:

```
0-a
1-b
2-c
```