# How to print out a numbered IP Address in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, ip-address

Let say `IP_Addresses` is the variable for IP Addresses.

```
>>> IP_Addresses = '''
... 1.1.1.1
... 2.2.2.2
... 3.3.3.3
... '''
>>>
```

If I use enumerate solution from this question, I did not get proper IP Adresss

[How to print out a numbered list in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29811082/how-to-print-out-a-numbered-list-in-python-3)

```
>>> for number, IP_Address in enumerate(IP_Addresses):
...     print(number, IP_Address)
... 
0 

1 1
2 .
3 1
4 .
5 1
6 .
7 1
8 

9 2
10 .
11 2
12 .
13 2
14 .
15 2
16 

17 3
18 .
19 3
20 .
21 3
22 .
23 3
24 

>>>
```

Desired Output

```
1 - 1.1.1.1
2 - 2.2.2.2
3 - 3.3.3.3
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split string using a newline delimiter with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22042948/split-string-using-a-newline-delimiter-with-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could split the variable by newline, like so:

```py
IP_Addresses = '''
... 1.1.1.1
... 2.2.2.2
... 3.3.3.3
... '''

i = 0
IP_Addresses = IP_Addresses.split('\n')
for line in IP_Addresses:
    if line and any(char.isdigit() for char in line):
        i += 1
        print(f'{i} - {line}')
```

Output:

```sh
1 - ... 1.1.1.1
2 - ... 2.2.2.2
3 - ... 3.3.3.3
```

Comment: Thanks. Would it be possible to remove extra lines 0 and 4 in the output?

Answer (score 0):

You should really use lists instead of a long string making the `IP_Addresses` variable:

```
IP_Addresses = ["1.1.1.1","2.2.2.2","3.3.3.3"]
```

Then you won't need to split the input.

If you insist on using a long string, then use `.split("\n")` to split on new lines instead of `.`

Example:

```
for number, IP_Address in enumerate(IP_Addresses.split("\n")):
    print(number, IP_Address)
```

Comment: How do I remove extra lines `0` and `4` in the output?

Comment: These are added by the first and final blank lines in you strings, please check my new answer for a guide on how to use a list instead.

Comment: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'`

Comment: You don't need the split function when you're using a list.

Comment: Great! List's are the bread and butter of python programming, enjoy!